# Error when uploading crashlytics mapping file when building signed Apk

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

When building signed apk with proguard for Crashlytics

I am getting below error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileProProdRelease'.
> Expected file collection to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.
```

Project level gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

App Level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.0'
}
```

Android Studio version 4.0.1

Full stacktrace for the same

`Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileProProdRelease'. at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:163) at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:156) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52) at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected file collection to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files. at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getSingleFile(AbstractFileCollection.java:64) at org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection$getSingleFile.call(Unknown Source) at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.UploadMappingFileTask.uploadMappingFile(UploadMappingFileTask.groovy:60) at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28) at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:717) at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:684) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:476) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:461) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:444) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:93) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:237) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:208) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47) at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140) ... 34 more`

Comment: Which version of the Crashlytics Gradle Plugin are you using?

Comment: Crashlytics version updated in question @OlegKodysh

Comment: Updated for visibility.

Answer (score 1):

The “looking for one file, found no files” is caused by an incorrect configuration of plugins - you need to put dexguard before Crashlytics. However, if you put dexguard before Crashlytics you get the other bug about “obfuscatorVersion”, which the Firebase team is shipping a fix for next week.

Edit: This has been resolved by the latest Gradle plugin which has shipped over the week.

Comment: I have the same problem, the error is the next: Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileAppQa'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /codebuild/output/src143975395/src/App/app/build/outputs/mapping/App/qa/mapping.txt (No such file or directory)
 
this is really strange because it is working on my local machine but it is not working on the pipeline, but the code previous the migration from fabric to crashlytics is working well on my local and on the pipeline in aws

Comment: I'm using proguard, the gradle plugin is 3.3.3 and the gradle version is gradle-4.10.3

Comment: Hi @dicarlomagnus have you found any solution? i'm stuck with exact same problem

Comment: @ChetanGupta Not yet, but have an interesting finding, I created a local docker from AWS image containers, then did the same and I got the same error, I did a new project with the same version of Crashlytics and the same version of Gradle and I got the same error, so I used a newer version of Gradle (5.1.1) and it worked for the new project, so I'm updating the Gradle on the real project and I will see if it works as well.

Comment: @dicarlomagnus, I got it fixed yesterday, What I did, I went to the firebase dashboard, there at Crashlytics section I selected enable option, it showed be a loader with instruction to setup, instead of following those I just run my build and it worked.

Comment: @ChetanGupta thanks, for me, what worked was to update the Gradle version It was on 4.10.3, and I updated it to 5.1.1, because my firebase project was already well configured.